# How do I add trend lines to a chart?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

For the uninitiated, this is a trend line:
[image]

How do I do that in an Android charting library, like MPAndroidChart? I've already set up the necessary code to produce the needed line chart, but I have no idea how to overlay a trend line over it.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the trend line mathematically and add a new line to the chart for that new line. [Here's a tutorial on how to calculate trend lines](http://classroom.synonym.com/calculate-trendline-2709.html).

If you followed that tutorial it would give you the equation you could plug in some values to get the X and Y coordinates to plot on the chart.